# Mysql jdbc - Inserted values get deleted immediatly

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using the mysql java connector (mysql-connector-java-8.0.11) to access a database.
I open a connection and generate some tables. So far everything works.

But when I try to insert a value in one of the tables, the row gets deleted immediatly.

I use following code

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO database_upgrade (version) VALUES (?)");
stmt.setInt(1, newVersion);
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.close();
```

When I debug into the executeUpdate the insertId and updateCount are returned correctly. But when I look at the database the entry is missing.
The autoincrement id increased which indicates that the row was inserted and then deleted, but I don't know why.

Interesting point: If I use a new connection for this insert, everything works perfectly. But when I use the connection from the previous actions, it does not.

Just for clarification

- All previous statements are closed
- The connection is still open
- The previous Actions are some "create table" and "alter table"

Can anyone tell me why this happens? I used the same code with MS SQL server and this did not happen.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you `setAutoCommit(false)` on the connection?

Comment: That's it! Although I did not set it myself. I just used the sql-export from phpmyadmin and in there there was a "set autocommit = 0". Thank you for the tipp!

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Gord Thompson I found it. The autocommit was turned off by some previous sql commands (that I did not double check).

Solution: I removed the autoCommit disabling part in my sql files.